# Question on limits

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Let $$L=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}-\frac{x^2}{4}}{x^4}$$.where L is a finite real number. Then value of a,L for which this is true . Options were there answer is $a=2,L=1/64$. $$\text{My Try}$$. I separated first terms of a and x ie first two terms and third term.Thinking quite a while I multiplied by conjugate of  the first two terms. Last term is in $x$ so $x^2$ cancels from numerator,denominator so we are left with $1/4x^2$ as x goes to infinity this goes to $0$. So this term is gone. Now I am thinking whether to solve this equation of two unknowns ie $L=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{x^2(a+\sqrt{a^2-x^2})}$. Or is there any better approach.

Comment: The function is only defined for $-|a|\le x\le|a|$ and $x\ne0$, so the limit at $\infty$ doesn't make sense. Perhaps it's the limit for $x\to0$.

Comment: @egreg WolframAlpha gives the result at infinity, for $a=2$, $L=0$

Comment: @windircurse WolframAlpha also uses complex numbers, but I don't think they're to be used here.

Answer (score 4):

The limit at $\infty$ doesn't make sense, because the function is only defined in $[-|a|,|a|]\setminus\{0\}$.

You probably want
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}-\frac{x^2}{4}}{x^4}
&=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(a-\frac{x^2}{4})^2-(a^2-x^2)}{x^4}
\frac{1}{a-\frac{x^2}{4}+\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}
\\
&=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-\frac{ax^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{16}+x^2}{x^4}
\frac{1}{a-\frac{x^2}{4}+\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}
\end{align}
and now it should be clear that if $a\ne2$, the limit is not finite.

For $a=2$ the limit is indeed $1/64$.